# What to choose after MBA finance major?

Tags: finance, financial-markets, financial

Particularly my younger sister is bit confused about what she can expertise in after doing MBA finance major.

She has her final year this year, post which she wants some short term courses or programs to clear that can help her excel what she is going to have a major in. She has cleared her 1st year with 87 percentile as grade A and stood with distinction in grads in accounts and commerce stream. She is brilliant in accountancy and Mathematics.

She was thinking to start with CA, CS or CFA studies or any finance courses or certifications which can internationally recognise and value it. She wants her first job in a foreign country, preferably in UK coz she wants to get settled there.

I suggested her to look for some experts help, read latest industry news or ask her college alumni. Can any industry professionals or finance domain expert guide her? Write me your views. I will convey her. She doesn't use social apps much.